# What are the maximum number of iPAddress add tags in the ipSecurity node in web config in IIS by version?

Tags: iis, web-config

What are the maximum number of iPAddress add tags in the ipSecurity node in web config in IIS by version?

I have been getting some strange results (incorrect page renderings and 500 errors) when adding 4 more add tags today.

I have been adding them via NotePad and FTP for a long time but then today I seen the errors.

I removed the new tags and everything started working again.

Added tags below.  These IPs have been hitting our site with the exact same number of hits and are all in the abuseipdb database. We wish to block everything from those servers.

I do not see anything wrong with the format of the tags.

```
<add ipAddress="58.82.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="false"/> <!-- 58.82.170.10 Thailand 2019-01-06 -->
<add ipAddress="217.160.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="false"/> <!-- 217.160.143.196 Germany -->
<add ipAddress="94.126.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="false"/> <!-- 94.126.168.68 Portugal-->
<add ipAddress="37.59.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="false"/> <!-- 37.59.46.60 France -->
```

Comment: If you are using such rules to block unwanted access, you probably should stop and use a full feature firewall instead.

Comment: This is in a shared environment and I don't have that option.

Comment: I have also created a test demo with six tags on my side, it works well.Could you please share the details error message about the 500 error? Besides, I suggest you could post the details web.config setting you have used in your application.

Comment: I have many other ipAddress'es in the web config not just those. I believe there are about 93 of them.

I can't tell much about the 500 error.  One of our php registration scripts crashes with when those 4 new items are in the web config, works when then are not.

Is there a definite answer to my original question about max number of ipAddress's?????

The entire web config file is about 31k.